# Replace formulas in-place in Excel with regex

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I have a sheet where I need to replace several hundred formulas that are all similar format. Basically, I need to remove IF statements and the second part of those statements in the formula. My idea was to search for all cells that have "IF($B$2=$BF$3," and then in those cells replace that bit with "" and then replace everything including and after the next "," with "" again. But the VBA gives me "runtime error 1004 application or user-defined error."
This would need to leave the "=" in the beginning obviously. Code below.

```
Sub Replace()
Set rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F36:AG231")
For Each c In rng
If InStr(1, ActiveCell.Formula, "IF", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
y = ActiveCell.Formula
pos_1 = InStr(1, y, ",", vbTextCompare)
pos_2 = InStr(1 + pos_1, y, ",", vbTextCompare)
ActiveCell = "=" & Mid(y, 1 + pos_1, Len(y) - (1 + pos_2))
End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you removing all `IF`s in the range of `"F36:AG231"`, or just this particular one of `IF($B$2=$BF$3,` ?

Comment: it runs fine on my rig, of course you need to add some kind of offset like "activecell.offset(1,0).select" between the "End If" and "Next" lines

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use regex?  If not, loop through the following

```
If InStr(1, ActiveCell.Formula, "IF", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
    y = ActiveCell.Formula
    pos_1 = InStr(1, y, ",", vbTextCompare)
    pos_2 = InStr(1 + pos_1, y, ",", vbTextCompare)
    ActiveCell = "=" & Mid(y, 1 + pos_1, Len(y) - (1 + pos_2))
Else
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for a single `IF` Statement - but will need some further tuning on the order of the RegExp if you have multiple `IF` replacements inside each other.

A formula of
`=1+IF($B$2=$BF$3,7,10)`
becomes
`=1+7`

*potental mode*
If you wanted to remove the `IF` altogther use,
`X(lngRow, lngCol) = .Replace(X(lngRow, lngCol), "0")`
rather than
X(lngRow, lngCol) = .Replace(X(lngRow, lngCol), "$1")

so
A formula of
`=1+IF($B$2=$BF$3,7,10)`
becomes
`=1+0`

*code*

```
Sub WhatIf()
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim X
Dim objRegex As Object
Dim objRegMC As Object
Dim lngRow As Long
Dim lngCol As Long

Set rng1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F36:AG231")
X = rng1.FormulaR1C1
Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

With objRegex
.Pattern = "IF\(.+?,(.+?),.+?\)"
.Global = False
For lngRow = 1 To UBound(X, 1)
For lngCol = 1 To UBound(X, 2)
Do While .test(X(lngRow, lngCol))
X(lngRow, lngCol) = .Replace(X(lngRow, lngCol), "$1")
Loop
Next
Next
End With

rng1.Value2 = X
End Sub
```